# Do you need to free a struct pointer before setting it to a new value?

Tags: memory, struct, allocation

I have a struct:

```
        struct Foo
        {
            int x;
            int  *ptr;
            void *ptr2;
        };
```

If I allocate memory for ptr using:

```
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and later I want to it to point it to something else that already has memory allocated for it, do I need to free ptr before doing:

```
        ptr = *other_variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't free before losing the pointer, the free never happens and you leak memory. So yes, you should do that.

Also, you probably want `ptr = &other_variable` rather than `*other_variable`, unless `other_variable` is of type `int **`.